# Can I share a texture 2D with ArraySize > 1 between 2 D3D11Device?

Tags: directx

I need to share a 2D texture with multiple levels, the documentation says you can not share mipmap textures, it does not talk about array size. But when I try with the GetSharedHandle and OpenSharedRessource methods, only the texture at index 0 works, the other index are corrupted. So is it possible?

Comment: What Direct3D feature level is your Direct3D 11 device? What version of the OS are you using?

Comment: D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_1 on windows 10 last update